# Hide Wordpress page contents when on Gravity Form inner pages

Tags: wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I have a multi-page gravity form. I've echoed it using do_shortcode within the theme template.

I have content on the same page below the gravity form (which resides inside the wp editor (the_content() wrapped in a div with its own class) ).

Is there a way for me to hide this content on page 2 or later of the gravity form? I would still like it to appear on page 1 of the gf form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here was the final code that worked for me:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).bind('gform_post_render', function(event, form_id, current_page){
        jQuery('.page-content').toggle(current_page == 1);
    });
</script>
```

I placed this in header.php

Answer (score 0):

Lets say the class name of the div that is wrapping the_content() is "entry-content" and you want to hide it when the form is on second page. Add the following jQuery code to your theme and It will hide that div when someone goes to 2nd page. If they return back to 1st page of the form. It will show the content again.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).bind('gform_page_loaded', function(event, form_id, current_page){
    if(current_page == "1"){
      jQuery('.entry-content').show();
    } else {
      jQuery('.entry-content').hide();
    }
});
// ]]></script>
```

If you donot want to show the content even if they come back to page 1, then you can use the following code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">// <![CDATA[
jQuery(document).bind('gform_page_loaded', function(event, form_id, current_page){
      jQuery('.entry-content').hide();
});
// ]]></script>
```

Documentation : https://www.gravityhelp.com/documentation/article/gform_page_loaded/